# The most appropriate protocol (SOAP or REST) to use with a *mobile OS?

Tags: rest, mobile, soap

What is the most appropriate protocol (**SOAP** or **REST** with JSON format) to use with a **mobile OS** Android or iOS application that uses a web services exposed by a Java/Java EE application?

Which one is going to be more performant and providing security, atomic transaction and reliability?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to define your security requirements a little better.

SOAP with WS-Security can be used to ensure the integrity of message, and that only the appropriate process can use the data.

It this is what you mean by security, you're better of with SOAP as it has handling capabilities for this.

REST is built ontop of standard HTTP operations: GET,PUT,DELETE,POST, and as such, security is based on two areas:

1. End to End security, provided by SSL (HTTP)
2. Authentication, which range from basic HTTP authentication, to custom providers, such as OAUTH2.

From a development perspective, REST based APIs, using JSON dataformat are easier to work with.

Comment: With REST, do i have to handle authentication with a programmatic way or is there any way to do it with a declarative and transparent way like Spring Security do for handling authentication in a Java/Java EE application? Do i need any third-party component ?

Comment: With REST, do i have to handle authentication with a programmatic way or is there any way to do it with a declarative and transparent way like Spring Security do for handling authentication in a Java/Java EE application? Do i need any third-party component ?

Answer (score -2):

My vote goes with REST with JSON.